# Google play says my app has 0 app excluded but there are devices that can't find it

Tags: android, device, google-play

I just uploaded a Phonegap made app to google play and it displays that there are 0 devices excluded for it. This isn't true at all, since a friend cannot find the app by searching via google play. His device is a galaxy mini running Android 2.2, but as I said, my google play control panel says 0 devices excluded so I don't know the reason/what to do.I have allowed all screen types in my manifest and target sdk from 8 to 17.

Do anybody have a clue what's going on?

App name: Txorierri turismo.

Comment: I have search your app in galaxy s3 its showing in it and I have installed it. May be your apps is not compatible with your friends mobile.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that the direct link displays a "your device is not compatible" message in my friends phone. Don't know the reason though. Anyways thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluded is not the same as "not available."

You can choose specific devices and manually force them to be excluded, but they DO have to be compatible with your app, anyway.

If your app is only for large devices, for instance, all non-large devices won't see yout app in Play at all. You can choose some large devices, though, and exclude them, so they also won't be able to see the app (despite the fact of meeting your app's requirements).

Answer (score 1):

So I finally find the problem, it has to do with galaxy mini model, if you have permission for camera in you manifest the app won't be available for this device. Hope this helps someone! Thanks!

Comment: That's obviously a bug then... Because the Samsung Galaxy Mini does have a camera according to http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-GALAXY-mini_id5147